# Problems mounting ntfs hard disk on boot

Tags: boot, mount, ntfs, drive

I've followed this tutorial:
[Can I change personal folder locations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110171/can-i-change-personal-folder-locations)
to mount my two disks on boot.

The funny thing is that I was able to mount one (Datos), but the second (Programs) gives me this error when I start the computer:

```
An error occurred while mounting /media/Programs, Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

I've also followed the steps here: [After upgrade to 11.10. An error occurred while mounting / root filesystem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1860852) but it didn't work out either.

Here is my output of `blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Datos" UUID="06EC5B95EC5B7E3D" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Programs" UUID="4C1C26FF1C26E3A4" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="8b6ad8ec-046b-490a-af60-aed89651c33a" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb6: UUID="021ca0e0-bfec-42e4-bc80-f72ff41c4c6f" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc1: UUID="C8F81C73F81C61CC" TYPE="ntfs"
```

Here are the permissions on the `/media` folder:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Oct 11 03:01 Datos 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Oct 13 14:50 floppy -floppy0 
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 13 14:50 floppy0 
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Oct 17 14:30 Programs
```

Here is my `fstab`:

```
'#' / was on /dev/sdb6 during installation

UUID=021ca0e0-bfec-42e4-bc80-f72ff41c4c6f /               ext4   
errors=remount-ro 0       1

'#' swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation

UUID=8b6ad8ec-046b-490a-af60-aed89651c33a none            swap    sw  
0       0

/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0    
0

UUID=06EC5B95EC5B7E3D /media/Datos ntfs defaults 0 0

UUID=4C1C26FF1C26E3A4 /media/Programs nfts defaults 0 0
```

Any idea why following the same procedure Datos loads on boot and Programs gives me an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fstab` file has an error.

The last line, i.e.

```
UUID=4C1C26FF1C26E3A4 /media/Programs nfts defaults 0 0
```

has `ntfs` misspelt.

The correct line should be

```
UUID=4C1C26FF1C26E3A4 /media/Programs ntfs defaults 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I just finished transforming all nfts partitions to ext4, I know it's not the answer to my question but it worked...