# Change /home and other relevant locations

Tags: hard-drive, home-directory

On my laptop, I have Windows 8 installed (on the internal solid state drive). I have another external hard drive with an installation of Ubuntu (with the EFI, `/`, `/home`, and swap partitions located on it).

All of my data is located on my internal drive, because I don't bring my hard drive around with me everywhere. Thus, my `/home` folder (and all sub folders) don't really contain anything.

This isn't very major, but more of an inconvenience. To access any of my data, I have to manually select my internal drive, and go through a plethora of other folders. For example, most of my important data is located at `/media/D0BC1650BC163208/Users/my_user_name/skydrive`.

Of course, I can create symbolic links to get everywhere I want to, but it would be nice if I could simply change the `/home` folder (to `my_user_name`), my documents folder, etc.

Of course, I know I would have to make sure the internal drive always gets mounted first.

Is there a simple way to do this?

I think [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/110178/181108) might be the easiest way, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is technically possible to do this using a [bind mount in your fstab](https://superuser.com/questions/429901/could-i-add-an-item-in-etc-fstab-to-bind-an-old-directory-with-a-new-one). However, having your home directory on a Windows NTFS filesystem, as you are suggesting, will cause problems as NTFS doesn't support Unix permissions. (For instance, `sshd` checks the permissions in your `~/.ssh` directory and refuses to start if they are too liberal.)

Changing the document folder locations, as in [the answer you linked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110171/can-i-change-personal-folder-locations/110178#110178), is a better solution. Well-behaved apps will default to the chosen location on your internal drive in their Save As dialogs, etc.; they will still store their configuration in your Linux home directory, avoiding permissions problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same task and I ran these comands (in 12.04LTS) to solve it, using the explanation of the URL: 
http://efectoreinaroja.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/cambiar-ubicacion-de-directorio-home/ (In Spanish) 
and it WORK PERFECTLY!:

1. I have a partition for Windows Data in ntfs: named /sda6 but you must use your ntfs partition)
   Atention this partition must not contain Windows OS!
   and you must have installed "ntfs-3g".
2. I Mount this partition in /media (but you can use /mnt too): 
   sudo mkdir /media/whome
   sudo mount /dev/sda6 /media/whome
3. Now I copied the directory /home to the directory /media/whome (using cpio instead cp)
   cd /home/
   sudo find . -depth -print0 | cpio --null --sparse -pvd /media/whome/
4. Now I dismount the partition:
   sudo umount /media/whome
5. Now to prevent keep the old home in backup folder:
   sudo mv /home /respaldo
6. Now mount the new partition /home:
   sudo mkdir /home
   sudo mount /dev/sda6 /home
7. Now the most important, to mount this partition every boot system:
   sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bk   (security backup)
   sudo gedit /etc/fstab

   and add this line at the end:
   /dev/sda6 /home  ntfs  nodev,nosuid  0  2

and thats all

If all work well, then you can remove the backup home data:
    rm -r /respaldo